# script not reading past while ($stmt->fetch())

Tags: php, html, mysql

Server won't read past while `($stmt->fetch())`

```
if (isset($_POST['join'])) {
$selectedgame = $_POST['join'];
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT tournaments FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $param_username);
if($stmt->execute()) { 
   //will read up until this point
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     //won't read here e.g. won't echo anything
    $stmt->bind_result($usertournaments);
    if ($usertournaments == 0) {
```

I have no idea what is causing the issue, `mysqli_error($link)` gives nothing, instructions are not wrong, checked a million times

please help D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $param_username);
                   ^
```

The first value of `bind_param` is the datatype. `i` is for an integer. I'd guess `username` is always a string so you should use the `s`.

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);
```

Also is `$param_username` set somewhere? It looks like the `POST` value is being set to `$selectedgame`, not sure that's related.

Comment: I can't believe i just made the two dumbest mistakes of my life, `$stmt->bind_result($usertournaments);` was placed after execution and `$stmt->bind_param("i", $param_username);` is supposed to be a s